# some peoples told me that using mxml is harmful for performance

Tags: actionscript

i am making business card studio(Editor) for web to print solution. and some peoples told me that using mxml is harmful for performance of software so that just use action-script instead of using flex mxml. So I am pretty confused that what to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActionScript is quicker than MXML, but for what you're going to do, you're trading speed for convenience - MXML comes with all the different UI classes (List, Scrollbars etc) already there; in pure AS3, you'd have to roll your own, or use something like MinimalComps: http://www.minimalcomps.com/

In any case, for what you're doing, performance doesn't matter (as long as it's not terrible :D) - a business card editor doesn't need to run at 60fps, so just use what you're familiar with/is the most convenient.